# Pitney Bownes Location API from NodeJS -> [Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE]

Tags: node.js, geolocation, ibm-cloud, pitney-bowes

I'm trying to send the access the Pitney Bownes Reverse-Geolocation API using the Request Module in NodeJS.

Sending the following HTTP request returns an error.

```
request("https://pitneybowes.pbondemand.com/location/address/lookup.json?latitude=LAT&longitude=LONG&searchDistance=1000&appId=APP_ID", function (err, res, body) {});
```

> [Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE]

Hitting this same URL in my browser returns the JSON response expected.

What's going wrong with the request sent from the NodeJS platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the server's certificate CA, there's an issue with the intermediate SSL certificate not being properly configured.

We can modify the request call to include a property to ignore this error at runtime.

```
request({
  url: url,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})
```

The external service provider has verified this issue exists within their API and provided an alternative solution that involves importing the certificates on your local system.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff is right about the SSL certificate.  An alternative is to set

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Here's the source to a picture finder app in IBM DevOps services that shows the fix.  https://hub.jazz.net/project/jstart/Picture%20Finder%20(Node)/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/jstart%252FPicture.Finder.%2528Node%2529/contents/master/app/app.js